# What Does tf.estimator.LinearClassifier() Do?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, tensorflow2.0

In TensorFlow library, what does the `tf.estimator.LinearClassifier` class do in linear regression models? (In other words, what is it used for?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear Classifier is nothing but Logistic Regression.

According to Tensorflow documentation, [tf.estimator.LinearClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier) is used to

> Train a linear model to classify instances into one of multiple
> possible classes. When number of possible classes is 2, this is binary
> classification

Linear regression predicts a value while the linear classifier predicts a class. Classification aims at predicting the probability of each class given a set of inputs.

For implementation of `tf.estimator.LinearClassifier`, please follow [this](https://www.guru99.com/linear-classifier-tensorflow.html#7) tutorial by guru99.

To know about the linear classifiers, read [this](https://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/) article.